# Kurtosis is greater or equal to square of skewness plus one

Tags: self-study, skewness, moments, kurtosis

Given is a random variable $X$ with finite fourth moment. Let $\gamma_3$ and $\gamma_4$ denote its skewness and kurtosis respectively.

I want to prove that $$\gamma_4\geq 1+ \gamma_3^2$$

I have seen a few proofs about the multidimensional case, but is there a simpler proof for the one-dimensional case?